# tkz-linknodes, subfig problems of alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats

I don't succeed in managing the alignment among the various figures. How can I do?
thanks

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[upright]{fourier}
    \usepackage{amsmath,tkz-linknodes,tikz,subfig}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[][]{\label{fig:prodottopolinomiopolinomio}
    \begin{minipage}{12cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) {$(A$};
    \node (p1)[right of=a, node distance=15]{$+$};
    \node (b)[right of=p1, node distance=15]{$B)^2$};
    \node (R)[right of=b, node distance=15]{$=$};
    \node (as)[right of=R, node distance=15]{$A^2$};
    \node (s1)[right of=as, node distance=15]{$+$};
    \node (bs)[right of=s1, node distance=15]{$B^2$};
    \node (s2)[right of=bs, node distance=15]{$+$};
    \node (dp)[right of=s2, node distance=15]{$2AB$};
    \path (a.north) edge [bend left=45,-triangle 90](as.north);
    \path (a.north) edge [bend left=45,-triangle 90](dp.north);
    \path(b.south)edge [bend right=45,-triangle 90](bs.south);
    \path(b.south)edge [bend right=45,-triangle 90](dp.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    }%
    \subfloat[][]{\label{fig:polinomiquadratobinomio1}
    \begin{minipage}{12cm}
    \begin{NodesList}
        \begin{align*}
            \left(a+2b\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
            +a^2&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
            +4b^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
            +4ab&\AddNode[3]\\
            \left(a+2b\right)^2=a^2+4b^2+4ab&\AddNode[4]
        \end{align*}
        \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$a\cdot a$}%    
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2b\cdot 2b$}%
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot a \cdot 2b$}%
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{ottengo}% 
    \end{NodesList}
    \end{minipage}
    }%
    \qquad%
    \subfloat[][]{\label{fig:polinomiquadratobinomio2}
    \begin{minipage}{12cm}%
    \begin{NodesList}
        \begin{align*}
            \left(2x-3y\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
            +4x^2&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
            +9y^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
            -12xy&\AddNode[3]\\
            \left(2x-3y\right)^2=4x^2+9y^2-12xy&\AddNode[4]
        \end{align*}
        \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2x\cdot 2x$}%    
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$(-3y)\cdot (-3y)$}%
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot (2x) \cdot(-3y)$}%
        \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{ottengo}% 
    \end{NodesList}
    \end{minipage}
    }%
    \subfloat[][]{\label{fig:polinomiquadratobinomio3}
    \begin{minipage}{12cm}%
    \begin{NodesList}
        \begin{align*}
        \left(2-z\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +4&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +z^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        -4z&\AddNode[3]\\
        \left(2-z\right)^2=4+z^2-4z&\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}
    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot 2$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$(-z)\cdot (-z)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot (2) \cdot(-z)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{ottengo}% 
    \end{NodesList}
    \end{minipage}
    }

    \caption{Quadrato Binomio}
      \label{fig:QuadratobinomioG}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

I tried to get an alignment of the type

AA

AA.

I didn't want an alignment of the type

A

A

A

A

```
enter code here
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-linknodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[h]{7cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-0.3,-1) rectangle (4.6,1.4);
\node (a) {$(A$};
\node (p1)[right of=a, node distance=15]{$+$};
\node (b)[right of=p1, node distance=15]{$B)^2$};
\node (R)[right of=b, node distance=15]{$=$};
\node (as)[right of=R, node distance=15]{$A^2$};
\node (s1)[right of=as, node distance=15]{$+$};
\node (bs)[right of=s1, node distance=15]{$B^2$};
\node (s2)[right of=bs, node distance=15]{$+$};
\node (dp)[right of=s2, node distance=15]{$2AB$};
\path (a.north) edge [bend left=45,-triangle 90](as.north);
\path (a.north) edge [bend left=45,-triangle 90](dp.north);
\path(b.south)edge [bend right=45,-triangle 90](bs.south);
\path(b.south)edge [bend right=45,-triangle 90](dp.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{aaaaaa}\label{fig:QuadratobinomioGa}%
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[h]{8cm}
\begin{NodesList}
\centering
    \begin{align*}  \left(a+2b\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +a^2&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +4b^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        +4ab&\AddNode[3]&\\
        \left(a+2b\right)^2=a^2+4b^2+4ab&\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}
    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$a\cdot a$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$2b\cdot 2b$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$2\cdot a \cdot 2b$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{ottengo}% 
\end{NodesList}
\subcaption{bbbbbb}\label{fig:QuadratobinomioGb}%
\end{minipage}%
\qquad%
\begin{minipage}[h]{8cm}
\begin{NodesList}
\centering
    \begin{align*}  \left(2x-3y\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +4x^2&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +9y^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        -12xy&\AddNode[3]\\
        \left(2x-3y\right)^2 =4x^2+9y^2-12xy&\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}
    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
    \LinkNodes[margin=0cm]{$2x\cdot 2x$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=0cm]{$(-3y)\cdot (-3y)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=0cm]{$2\cdot (2x) \cdot(-3y)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=0cm]{ottengo}% 
\end{NodesList}
\subcaption{cccc}\label{fig:QuadratobinomioGc}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[h]{8cm}
\begin{NodesList}
\centering
    \begin{align*}
        \left(2-z\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +4&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +z^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        -4z&\AddNode[3]\\
        \left(2-z\right)^2=4+z^2-4z&\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}
    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$2\cdot 2$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$(-z)\cdot (-z)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{$2\cdot (2) \cdot(-z)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=1cm]{ottengo}% 
\end{NodesList}
\subcaption{ddddd}\label{fig:QuadratobinomioGd}%
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Quadrato Binomio}
  \label{fig:QuadratobinomioG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

it works

Comment: You should make sure that your posts are properly formatted: Highlight code blocks and press the `{}` button, and make sure that there isn't an excessive amount of empty lines. The code should be compilable as is: Please make sure that it compiles if you copy-and-paste the code into a new document (the empty lines break the code). Also, could you explain in a little more detail what result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Of course you can't get a 2x2 alignment if the four parts are 12cm wide: you'd need the page width to be at least 24cm.

Answer (score 4):

If you replace the `=` with `&=` on the *last* line of the `align*` environment yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- Eliminated excessive new lines (they are not allowed within an `align` environment), and were also effecting the picture as well.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-linknodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[][]{\label{fig:prodottopolinomiopolinomio}
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {$(A$};
\node (p1)[right of=a, node distance=15]{$+$};
\node (b)[right of=p1, node distance=15]{$B)^2$};
\node (R)[right of=b, node distance=15]{$=$};
\node (as)[right of=R, node distance=15]{$A^2$};
\node (s1)[right of=as, node distance=15]{$+$};
\node (bs)[right of=s1, node distance=15]{$B^2$};
\node (s2)[right of=bs, node distance=15]{$+$};
\node (dp)[right of=s2, node distance=15]{$2AB$};
\path (a.north) edge [bend left=45,-triangle 90](as.north);
\path (a.north) edge [bend left=45,-triangle 90](dp.north);
\path(b.south)edge [bend right=45,-triangle 90](bs.south);
\path(b.south)edge [bend right=45,-triangle 90](dp.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}%

\subfloat[][]{\label{fig:polinomiquadratobinomio1}

\begin{minipage}{12cm}
\begin{NodesList}
    \begin{align*}  \left(a+2b\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +a^2&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +4b^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        +4ab&\AddNode[3]&\\
        \left(a+2b\right)^2&=a^2+4b^2+4ab\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}

    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}

    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$a\cdot a$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2b\cdot 2b$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot a \cdot 2b$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{ottengo}% 
\end{NodesList}
\end{minipage}%
}%

\qquad%
\subfloat[][]{\label{fig:polinomiquadratobinomio2}

\begin{minipage}{12cm}%
\begin{NodesList}
    \begin{align*}  \left(2x-3y\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +4x^2&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +9y^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        -12xy&\AddNode[3]\\
        \left(2x-3y\right)^2 &=4x^2+9y^2-12xy\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}

    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}

    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2x\cdot 2x$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$(-3y)\cdot (-3y)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot (2x) \cdot(-3y)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{ottengo}% 
\end{NodesList}
\end{minipage}%
}%

\subfloat[][]{\label{fig:polinomiquadratobinomio3}

\begin{minipage}{12cm}%
\begin{NodesList}
    \begin{align*}
        \left(2-z\right)^2&\AddNode[1]\AddNode[2]\AddNode[3]\AddNode[4]\\
        +4&\AddNode[1]&\\ 
        +z^2&\AddNode[2]&\\
        -4z&\AddNode[3]\\
        \left(2-z\right)^2&=4+z^2-4z\AddNode[4]
    \end{align*}
    \tikzset{LabelStyle/.style = {left=0.1cm,pos=0.5,text=red,fill=white}}
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot 2$}%    
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$(-z)\cdot (-z)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{$2\cdot (2) \cdot(-z)$}%
    \LinkNodes[margin=2cm]{ottengo}% 
\end{NodesList}
\end{minipage}%
}

\caption{Quadrato Binomio}
  \label{fig:QuadratobinomioG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have thought that the OP was trying to get all subfigures centered, or aligned among the same vertical axis in some way ("the alignment among the various figures"). There's no way of knowing without their input, however.

Comment: @Jake: I thought it was about the alignment of the elements in that actual pictures themselves. You can take this code and do the sub-figure alignment, and I will delete this...

Comment: Oh no, I don't know if that's what they meant! I'd just leave your answer there, and see if the OP clarifies their question.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment (now deleted) `I tried to get autoallineamento of the type AA. AA I didn't want an alienation of the type A A A A`.  Please edit the question and provide some more details.

Comment: 12cm*2=24cm  my problem doesn't have solution!! excuse me

Comment: Ok, hopefully the other changes I made helped.